# How to generate SSH key for use with Puppet and Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops, version-control, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am new to Puppet and I face a problem with the existing setup. The puppet git repository resides in Azure DevOps.

When I run the command

```
puppet access login
-> admin credentials are successfully authenticated
puppet code deploy <env> --wait
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine current branches for Git source 'puppet'
(/etc/puppetlabs/code-staging/environments)\nOriginal exception:
\nnvalid or unknown remote ssh hostkey at
/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/code-manager/worker-caches/
deploy-pool-1-1/git@ssh.dev.azure.com-v3-org-project-gitRepoName\n"
```

After digging a little bit I generated a new ssh keygen file from which I got a public key and private key on the Puppet Eterprise hosted server. However, I am not sure where to upload these files so that Puppet can start looking for code changes from this repository.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to add your public SSH key to Azure Devops.

1.Copy your public SSH key.

2.In the Azure DevOps Services web UI, open the user menu, click Security, and then click SSH public keys.

3.Click Add and paste your public SSH key into the Key Data field.
Add a description and click Save.
[image]

For more information, please read this document:

https://www.puppet.com/docs/continuous-delivery/4.x/integrations.html#integrate_azure_devops

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This part is already done. I still get the error "Invalid or unknown remote ssh hostkey at /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/code-manager/worker-caches/deploy-pool-1-1/git@ssh.dev.azure.com-v3-org-proj-repo"

Comment: Have you followed the steps in this [guide](https://www.puppet.com/docs/continuous-delivery/4.x/integrations.html#integrate_azure_devops) to integrate with devops servcie? Since you have added your public SSH key in devops web UI,it highly may be a problem with the puppet configuration. Please check the guide again  or you can send a pot on puppet community to get professional suggestions.